# Add CSS Style to textarea that shows XML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Would like to know if that's a possible idea .

I have an `<textarea>` on my page that shows formatted XML . 
At the moment it appears as regular text, and although it's not bad, i though about adding CSS to that `<textarea>` that it will show up these XML with colors, similiar to the way Notepad++ shows XML .

This is how it looks now :
[image]

This is how i want it to look :
[image]

Comment: Not possible with a textarea.

Comment: Plenty of libraries that do it https://codemirror.net/ or https://github.com/google/code-prettify or a bunch of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to style things differently in textareas to get the effect you are after. The style you apply will be for everything in it, not portions.

What you would need to do is to process each line and generate html for it. It is pretty complicated, but there are plenty of projects that already do that for you.

Two popular ones are codemirror.net or github.com/google/code-prettify or a bunch of others.

Comment: Thank you, i'll use that . Hopefully it'll work out fine .